# C++, GCC: avoid evaluation of useless expressions

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, macros, evaluation

I defined a `Debug` class (similar to `qDebug` from Qt) with an `operator<<` to stream data to `stdout`.

According to its template parameter (that, in turn will depend on a macro `DEBUG`), `Debug` will be specialized: `operator<<` of a specialization will print data, while the one of the other specialization will be quiet.

The following is the quiet version:

```
template< bool quiet = true >
class _Debug
{
public:
    template< typename T >
    _Debug& operator<<( const T & )
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I noticed, however, that parameters to `operator<<` will be evaluated even if it's the quiet version:

```
Debug<1>() << "Var " << var.name();
```

I can see with a profiler that when running the above piece of code, expressions `"Var"` and `var.name()` are evaluated even if `Debug<1>` is the quiet specialization of `_Debug`.

Is there any way to avoid this? Maybe should I pass some options to GCC?

I thought that a similar solution using templates would be cleaner and perform better than a solution using macros, but was probably wrong...

Comment: Don't name your stuff like `_This`, it's reserved for the implementation.

Comment: How would the compiler know that var.name() is doing something valid or is something that doesn't need compiling?

Comment: C++11? Pass a lambda function which only gets executed in debug mode? Although, I've always just used `DEBUG && cout << "Var";` or something like that.

Comment: Does it matter whether the expression gets evaluated? The optimizer ought to take care of that if the ultimate function call does nothing. Then just apply a specialization.

Comment: @Kerrek: if the expression calls a function in a library or external module, the compiler probably will not have enough information to optimize it away.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: yes, it's C++11. What lambda function should I pass? `DEBUG &&` looks like a valid alternative, although I was hoping things like this could be done with templates without any penalty.
@KerrekSB: well, it's not working. `Var::name()` is defined within my source code and doesn't use external stuff (except for `std::string::operator+`, which I believe is defined in the header files), still GCC isn't able to optimize it away, not even with -O3...

Comment: @peoro: You could try with `-flto`... but it's a long shot.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how this can be achieved without macros. So for reference, here is a macro similar to what used in google-glog:

```
#define LOG (quiet) ? (void)0 : your_logging_object
```

where `quiet` is a boolean. Then elsewhere in your code:

```
LOG << some_var;
```

Comment: Skip the conditional compilation, and use a variable as the ternary operator control expression.

Comment: @thesamet: in my code I had something like: `auto dbg = Debug<5>(); while( ... ) dbg << something;`. Is there any way to adapt your solution in order to handle this case?

Comment: Would `#define dbg (quiet) ? (void)0 : your_real_dbg` do?